# Woocommerce subscriptions force new invoice every month

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on a subscription service that is contracted on a yearly basis, and invoiced monthly. We thought WC Subscriptions would be ideal, but we noticed that when a customer does not pay, the system just keeps the subscription on hold.

I'm looking for way to keep the subscription going and letting the system create a new order even when the last one hasn't been paid yet.

If I was able to prevent the subscription from being put on-hold after a new order is created, would that allow the second order to be created even when the previous is unpaid?